# What are the conditions for phase separation in a ternary mixture?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry

Consider a ternary solution with components $A, B, C$, with $B$ being a polymer degree of polymerization $N$. The dimensionless Flory-Huggins free energy density of mixing of this system is given by

$$ f = \phi_a \ln \phi _a + \frac{\phi _b}{N}\ln \phi_b + (1-\phi _a - \phi _b) \ln (1-\phi _a - \phi _b) + \phi _a \phi _b \chi _{ab} + \phi _a (1 - \phi _a - \phi _b) \chi _{ac} + \phi _b (1 - \phi _a - \phi _b) \chi _{ac}  $$

I understand that the spinodality condition of this system is
$$ D \equiv f _{\phi _a \phi _a} f _{\phi _b \phi _b} - f _{\phi _a \phi _b} ^2 = 0$$

But what is the nature of the phase separation? When inside the spinodal, how does the solution split up, assuming constant temperature and all the $\chi _{ij}$ are constant?

For example, if $D<0$, what are the other conditions required to form 2 phases of the form $(A+B,C)$ or $(A+C,B)$ or $(B+C,A)$ to form, versus what are the conditions to form 3 immiscible phases $(A,B,C)$?

Comment: Start with a simpler binary phase diagram first and understand it using ideal and regular solution models.

Comment: @JonCuster, thanks for your reply. For a simple binary solution, phase separation simply follows the spinodal condition $f_{\phi \phi} = 0$. In this case, one phase is "polymer rich" the other is "polymer lean". I do not see how this translates over to a ternary diagram, where I can have a solution in 3 phases where there is an "A-rich", "B-rich" and "C-rich" phase

Comment: Yes, there is an added dimension to play with in your mind. As an intermediate step, consider fixing one component (say C) and seeing how the pseudo binary system behaves as you trade off A and B.

Comment: @JonCuster, right, I do the same thing. I fix C, and do the FH analysis. My question is, I still get two phases, which I consider "B-rich" and "A-rich", with equal composition of C in both. How do I show that there can be three distinct regions?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the number of phases the equilibrium condition is that the fugacity (or the chemical potential) of component is the same in all phases. For three phases these conditions give six independent equations
$$\tag{1}
\begin{array}{c}
   f_A^\text{phase I} = f_A^\text{phase II} = f_A^\text{phase III}\\
   f_B^\text{phase I} = f_B^\text{phase II} = f_B^\text{phase III}\\
   f_C^\text{phase I} = f_C^\text{phase II} = f_B^\text{phase III}
\end{array}
$$
These are to be solved for six mol fractions, say,
$$
   x_A^\text{I},\quad
   x_A^\text{II},\quad
   x_A^\text{III},\quad
   x_B^\text{I},\quad
   x_B^\text{II},\quad
   x_B^\text{III} 
$$
with $x_C$ in each phase obtained from the condition, $x_A+x_B=x_C = 1$.

The fugacity in phase $\pi$ is
$$\tag{2}
   f_i^{\pi} = x_i^\pi \gamma_i^\pi P_i^\text{sat}
$$
with the activity coefficient $\gamma_i$ obtained from the Flory-Huggins equation. This expresses the activity coefficient in terms of mole fractions, so the equations (1) is a set of 6 equations for six unknown mole fractions. The saturation pressures are not needed because they cancel out, the only information needed are the activity coefficients of all components.

**Activity coefficient**

The activity coefficient of component is calculated from the excess free (Gibbs) energy of the solution. The general formula is
$$\tag{3}
   \ln \gamma_i = \frac{\partial (F^E/RT)}{\partial n_i}
$$
where $F = n_\text{tot} f$ is the total free energy of a solution that contains $n_i$ moles of each component. For binary mixtrure ($1 = \text{solvent}$, $2=\text{polymer}$) the free energy is
$$\tag{4}
   \frac{f^E}{RT} = \frac{F^E}{nRT} 
   = x_1 \ln \phi_1 + x_2 \ln \phi_2 + x_1\phi_2 \chi_{12}
$$
and the activity coefficients are
$$
\tag{5a}
   \ln \gamma_1 = \ln\frac{\phi_1}{x_1} 
   +\left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)\phi_2 + \chi_{12}\phi_2^2\\
$$
$$
\tag{5b}
   \ln\gamma_2
   = \ln\frac{\phi_2}{x_2}
   + (r-1)\Phi_1 
   + r\chi_{12}\phi_1^2
$$
where $r$ is the ratio of the molar volumes of the polymer relative to the solvent, $r = v_2/v_1$. In the special case of no interactions ($\chi_{12}=0$) the activity coefficients simplify to
$$
\tag{6}
  \ln\gamma_i = \frac{\phi_i}{x_i} .
$$

I don't have the activity coefficients for ternary mixture but these can be derived just as in the binary case by application of Eq. (3) with $F^E$ from Eq. (4).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Themis! How do i find the activity coefficient $\gamma$ from the FH free energy? I am not sure how to do this

Comment: I updated my answer with the calculation of the activity coefficient. For binary mixtures the activity coefficients are given in many textbooks. For the ternary case you may have to do the derivations yourself. I

Comment: Hi @Themis, thank you again!

Comment: Hi @Themis. The issue I am having right now is that all solutions seem to be coming to the same point. As in, $\phi_A ^{I} = \phi_A ^{II} = \phi_A ^{III} = 0.33$, and the same applies for $A,B,C$. How do I find a way around this?

Comment: For example, $\mu _A = \frac{dF}{dn_A} = \log \phi _A + 1 - \phi _A - \frac{v_A}{v_B} \phi _B - \frac{v_A}{v_B} \phi _C + v_A (\phi _B ^2 \chi _{AB} + \phi _C ^2 \chi _{AC} + \phi _B \phi _C (\chi _{AB} + \chi _{AC} - \chi _{BC}))$. My question is, how do I differentiate between the chemical potentials in phase I vs phase II?

Comment: @megamence This is a non linear system with multiple solutions, not all of them physical. The solution $\phi_A^I=\phi_A^{II}=\phi_A^{III}$ is trivial, which means that it satisfies the equations but makes all three phases identical. You need a non linear solver, and initial conditions away from the trivial case. Also, depending on the parameters the system may not be able to split in three phases but only in two. Do you have an actual system in mind, and what are the $\chi$ values?

Comment: I do have a system in mind. For example, I want to find how a system splits for $\chi _{ab} = \chi _{bc} = \chi _{ac} = 2.7$ for $v_a = v_b = v_c = 1$. I see multiple phases, but I am not sure how it all splits up, given that your are inside the spinodal which looks like a discontinuous region on a ternary plot.